# xsl to remove all 'string' type quotes before converting to json output for any boolean values

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I am using xsl to convert an xml into json.

The josn boolean values are showing up as `myboolean:"true"`. They should be showing up as `myboolean:true` (without the quotes around true).

How can I make xsl remove all 'string' type quotes before converting to json output for any boolean values?

Comment: You must post your xsl, sample input XML and corresponding json output before anybody can determine what's wrong.

Comment: I am basically wondering if it is possible to write an <xsl:template> to remove the quotes from the boolean values

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  If you show how the boolean values are being handled in your transform, we can show you how to adjust the transform.  The quotes could be produced for a variety of reasons, depending on what the source document content and the XSLT look like.

Comment: My guess is that you're thinking about this backwards. Your current stylesheet probably adds the quotes to the output for all text nodes. What you want is a template that *doesn't* add the quotes to the strings `true` or `false` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `translate()` function to strip out any double-quote `"` and single quote/apostrophe `'` characters from our string value, translating them into nothing:

```
translate(.,'&quot;&apos;','')
```

Comment: I've tried the following and it does not work "boolRes" : "<xsl:value-of select="translate(false(),'&#34;','')"/>"    I still have a json result of  "boolRes" : "false"  but would like to have "boolRes" : false